# Determining number of $j$ such that $b_j \le c_i$ and $a_j \le b_i$ in time $O(\log n)$

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have an array $A$ of length $n$, containing triplets (think of it as a $3\times n$ matrix). Can I re-order the array (without reordering a triplet's inner values) in time $O(n\log n)$ so that it is possible to answer the following query in $O(\log n)$? Given $i$, determine the number of $j$ such that $A_{2,j} \le A_{3,i}$ and $A_{1,j} \le A_{2,i}$.

Comment: How are they sorted? Using the lexicographical ordering?

Comment: Also, how would you want the algorithm to behave? would it be given some $i$ and required to return the number of elements for that $i$? or does it not get any additional input and has to output a list that contains in the $i$'th spot the number of elements for $i$?

Comment: If you want to determine something for every $i$, you need to determine $n$ numbers, which will take you $\Omega(n)$ time. Perhaps you are only given a specific $i$?

Comment: You can use [range trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) with [fractional cascading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_cascading).

Comment: Can you please give a reference (a link or something I can verify) to where you've encountered the problem? There is a simple solution (via sorting and computing minima on prefixes), but I'm reluctant to provide more details in case it's, for example, from an active programming context.